# No changes for files visible after stashing/unstashing

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-clone, git-stash, git-fetch

I'm not a GIT expert and had a strange situation. I've updated a project using something like this:

```
git -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin --progress --prune
```

but my changes were moved to a stash automatically (in fact I'm using `PhpStorm` and not command line). Then I unstashed them however GIT didn't see there were any changes for the modified files. The files themselves were modified, but when I tried to commit I had message there's nothing to commit.

As a workaround I archived the whole project directory, cloned the repo from origin and then using `Total Commander` I just made directory synchronization to move modified files to repo I've just cloned. This way GIT saw the files are modified and I could commit them.

But the question is - what could happened that GIT didn't see that files were modified and what to do in such situation in future not to use such not effective workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Note: unstash will modify the working tree, but not the index.

That means you would still need to add (git add .) before doing a git commit.

A commit right after unstash would indeed result in the message you saw.